# Is this python code relevant for merge sort?

Tags: python, debugging, mergesort

The code below is what i think should be the implementation of merge sort in Python and works as expected. It sorts the given list. But after considering some online implementations I am doubtful about my implementation. So the base question is "Is this even Merge sort?". Thank you for your time and effort in critiquing this code:

```
def merge(arr):
    # base case
    length = len(arr)
    half = length//2
    if length == 1 or length == 0:
        return arr
    # recursive case
    firstHalf = merge(arr[:half])  # sort first half
    secondHalf = merge(arr[half:])  # sort second half
    length_firstHalf = len(firstHalf)
    length_secondHalf = len(secondHalf)
    sortedList = []

    i, j = 0, 0  # variables for iteration
    while i != length_firstHalf and j != length_secondHalf:  # add elements into the new array until either of then two sub arrays is completely traversed
        if firstHalf[i] > secondHalf[j]:
            sortedList.append(secondHalf[j])
            j += 1
            continue
        if firstHalf[i] < secondHalf[j]:
            sortedList.append(firstHalf[i])
            i += 1
    return(sortedList + firstHalf[i:] + secondHalf[j:])  # return the array after adding whats left of sub array which wasnt completely traversed 
print(merge([20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]))
```

Comment: You should consider moving this question to Code Review Stack Exchange at https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ye it is, you just wrote the merge function inside the master function itself, it could have been a separate function (cleaner).

Comment: The `while` loop is rather broken - it will loop forever if you encounter two equal values, as neither `i` nor `j` will advance.